# Где и как хранить данные пришедшие с сервера? И как ими манипулировать?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть простейший html код, который получает данные с jsonplaceholder и отображает их в html. Но я задался таким вопросом, что если мне случайно понадобилось сделать сортировку на клиенте? Тогда куда мне сохранить массив данных пришедших с сервера? Создавать глобальную переменную и пихать в нее данные?

и еще небольшой вопросик для знающих, мне пришел id какого-то продукта, я хочу добавить его в корзину, храню id в data-атрибуте data-id="id", что если пользователь нарочно зайдет и изменит этот атрибут на другой id? Как мне потом правильно синхронизировать товар, лежащий на сервере и лежащий в корзине с неправильным id?

Comment: "Создавать глобальную переменную и пихать в нее данные?" --- ну да. Либо в специальном классе, который занимается конкретными действиями с конкретными данными... ............. "Как мне потом паравильно синхронизировать товар лежащий на сервере и лежащий в корзине с неправильным id" --- а зачем и там и там корзина? Почему нельзя всё делать на клиенте, а на сервер отсылать то, что клиент навыбирал?

Comment: 1. Переменные, localstorage. 2. Никак. Скорее всего у Вас не будет такой ситуации (обычные пользователи не знают, что такое консоль), а если и будет - обрабатывайте как есть.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не очень понял про две корзины, на клиенте юзер изменил id на несуществующий, у меня есть корзина в которой лежат продукты условно в сессии, при например отправке их на сервер id соответственно неправильный, что делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: @user469485 зачем тебе корзина в сессии?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, у меня нет реализации корзины на бекенде, только фронтенд корзина. Я храню данные которые попали в корзину в сессии

Comment: @user469485 тогда про какую корзину в сесии  ты говоришь? и какую синхрлнизацию если у тебя корзина только на клиенте?.......... ещё раз: зачем тебе данные корзины в сессии?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Извиняюсь, может быть неправильно выразился, на бекенде нет например продукта с таким id, а он пришел, что делать в таких случаях, что сказать клиенту, и как правильно это обработать, если у меня будет сохраненный продукт в корзине с несуществующим id?

Comment: Наверное возвращать ошибку, что такого товара нет, например.

Comment: @Simon, а если клиент набрал много продуктов в корзину, всю ее обнулять?

Comment: @user469485 сам клиент менять ничего не будет.........а нафаня получит в ответ сообщение об ошибке..... вот и всё..........ну если так хочется, можно возврщать сообщение, что такие товары отсутсвуют в магазине, сорян

Comment: @user469485 "если клиент набрал много продуктов в корзину, всю ее обнулять" --- можно вернуть список товаров доступных к покупке, и сказать что только они доступны, остальные удалите из корзины

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, я понял, благодарю за ответы, тоесть это обычная практика хранить такие данные как id, в атрибутах например и в дальнейшем ими манипулировать?

Comment: Если используется просто js, а не какой-нибудь react или vue - вполне некоторые данные записывают в data атрибуты, да. Ничего страшного в этом нет.